# Editlog and fsimage

Tags: hadoop

I read some where that if namenode fails then we have to copy FsImage and editlog manually to secondary Namenode.But my question is if namenode is failed then from where we will get FsImage and Editlog file as both are the part of NameNode.

Can we store FsImage and EditLog outside of NameNode such as in NAS ?

Answer (score 0):

`FSImage` and `EditLog` is stored in `Persistent Storage(disk)`.

When Hadoop cluster starts,Namenode loads both `fsimage and editlog to the memory`.

**Please go through documentation below in order to have better understanding of Secondary Name Node.**

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_user_guide.html#Secondary+NameNode

Answer (score 0):

Well , We don't need to manually copy fsimage and editlogs to Namenode. Secondary Node is always having snapshot of Latest Metadata after merging these two files to create new fsimage. And whenever Namenode fails, once you restart it. It will get metadata from Secondary Namenode.